# Stub generic Interface with MS Fakes

Tags: c#, unit-testing, microsoft-fakes

How to create a Stub `IRepository<TModel>`? I have 3 interfaces:

```
namespace DataAccessLayer.Repository.Interfaces 
{
    public interface IRepository<TModel> : IDisposable {...}
    public interface ICustomerRepository : IRepository<CustomerModel> {...}
    public interface IRepositoryContainer {...}
}
```

My `DataAccessLayer.fakes` looks as follows:

```
<StubGeneration>
    <Clear/>
    <Add FullName="DataAccessLayer.Repository.Interfaces.IRepositoryContainer!"/>
    <Add FullName="DataAccessLayer.Repository.Interfaces.IRiadRepository!"/>
    <Add FullName="DataAccessLayer.Repository.Interfaces.IRepository!"/>
</StubGeneration>
```

In my unit tests I can see `StubIRepositoryContainer` and also `ICustomerRepository`, but stub for `IRepository<TModel>` is not generated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your name filtering is too limited.  Try removing the '!' from IRepository line in your fakes configuration file.

```
<Add FullName="DataAccessLayer.Repository.Interfaces.IRepository"/>
```

That raises the question if the syntax will allow filtering with the '!'.  The couple of variations I tried did not work ("IRepository!TModel").  Here's some information about [Parameter Naming Type Conventions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh708916.aspx#BKMK_Parameter_type_naming_conventions).